# In the google analytics Audience has data，real-time has not data

Tags: google-analytics, onsen-ui

I use the google analytics in my hybird applicaction using onsen ui and angularjs, but In the google analytics Audience has data，real-time report has not data.Anybody knows the reason？
My code as follows：

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height,  initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
<script src="components/loader.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script>
// PhoneGap event handler
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("PhoneGap is ready");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
!function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
(A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
}(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-x');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<h1>HelloWorld!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked with GA Debugger or by analysing the Network panel in a dev console to see if the hits are going through? RealTime may not always be reliable.

Comment: Could you tell me how to use GA Debugger to check it?I download the GA Debugger, but I do not know how to use it.

Comment: After you have installed the GA Debugger, make sure it is on, and also make sure you have console window open. Any output from the GA Debugger will be displayed in the console window. Through the tool, you will be able to see hits go through and the status of those hits.